# submit hadoop job on cloudera

Tags: hadoop, jobs, cloudera

I am wondering if we can setup a cloudera cluster on amazon and kick off a hadoop job from my local linux without ssh into amazon's node.

Is there anything like a client to do this communication?

Answer (score 1):

The tips from the following tutorial really work. You should be able to put a working Hadoop Cluster in under 20 minutes, from cold iron to production ready, using just his guidance:

- [Hadoop Quickstart: Build a Cluster In The Cloud In 20 Minutes](http://www.ctovision.com/2012/01/cloudera-hadoop-quickstart/)

Really worth checking it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an Hadoop client in your local linux and use the "hadoop jar" command with your own jar. Specify the option mapred.job.tracker in the command line and the client will push your jar to the jobtracker and duplicate it in all the tasktrackers that will be used for this job.